# Is there a way to find out how crowded a place can be during certain period?

Tags: europe, seasonal

This might be a very dumb question, but I love to visit places which are not very crowded.  For example, I am looking for some place, preferably on the sea, to visit in the first part of September (in Europe).  There are quite a few options that I can afford, but I was wondering if I could somehow find out if those places are usually crowded or not in September.  Is there any way except raw Google searching to do that?  I mean, I doubt there is some tool/application for that, but some tricks you might know?  Or some database, something like that?

Comment: Have you checked live webcams like https://www.skylinewebcams.com/en/webcam/italia/liguria/genova/boccadasse-genova.html  in Genoa?  you can get a feel for it. There's also tourist  stats produced by the Italian Govt.

Comment: @GayotFow as a cybersecurity student I find those cams very disturbing :D but useful nonetheless I guess... Though, it's only live I don't see an option to see some archive for other months... I'll google about tourist stats. thanks

Comment: Fortunately you have an astoundingly good answer, much better than passive observation.

Comment: You might notice that places you like are also liked by many other people. The least crowded places are usually the least attractive or convenient ones... ;)

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek in most cases your logic makes sense, but it's not always the case. People have different taste in everything and that applies for travelling as well, for me priorities are usually different than for most people when it comes to choosing a place, speaking for experience.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Google has a tool for this. it you search for a specific place, it will show you data Google has on how busy that place is on certain days and at certain times as a bar graph. Here is an example of the Louvre in Paris: https://www.google.com/search?q=louvre%20paris

[image: Screenshot of Google Search Result of Lourve with busy bar graph]

I believe these data are gathered from Google Maps or Android users' location.

In addition, to find out similar information for a general place, like a city or region, again Google its name and in the sidabar, select "Travel Guide" and scroll down, there should be this graph to give a general indication of popular times to visit:

[image: Paris when to visit from Google Travel Guide]

One caveat: I don't know if this works in all languages, but it seems to work for sure on English Google. So if it's not working, try visiting google.com and select the English language version.

Comment: thats not bad, though my question is more like about cities/towns... I'm not gonna spend a holiday in a museum you know...

Comment: See my edit. It's a little more generalized, but might be helpful.

Comment: Very good find! Even I didn't know about the Travel Guide part on Google.

Comment: Good for knowing when people with regular visitors are little, moderately, or very busy.  Major limitation: does not inform on how crowded less-visited places are, for those looking for secluded beaches for example.

Comment: True about the limitation. I think it only works for businesses as well, and maybe some large public attractions. But it is as far as I can tell the closest to a central, structured database of this kind of info.

Comment: In general for cities/towns you can check central places like the market place/shops on the main shopping street/mall,... to get an idea. If those are crowded, that usually indicates the nearby region is crowded. Or for the secluded beach, find the closes beach bar. (generally: check places people use for short visits for lunch/sightseeing when they are moving around the region in general)

Comment: Also (@gerrit) I have a suspicion it won't work for areas without a good mobile signal -- it relies on Google picking up people's phones with location on (and that requires GPS or multiple cellphone masts).  So it may be tricky to get data from even a popular beach under cliffs.  Without a large sample of people the data wouldn't be much use (so google may not present it)

Comment: @ChrisH I think it also relies on something being defined by Google as a "destination", which are not arbitrary places by lat/lons but is typically limited to (large-ish) public places like museums, train stations, airports, shopping centres, etc., although elsewhere on Google Maps the same technology is also used for traffic, it won't tell me how crowded the nearby woodland is despite mobile phone and GPS coverage there being excellent. I suspect some places (like small train stations or shops) may not have enough data either. No technical reason why it couldn't work for Scafell Pike, really.